# Cramer's Rule for $n$ unknowns?

Tags: determinant

I know Cramer's rule for $2$ and $3$ unknowns.

Is there a Cramer's Rule for $n≥4$? (where $n$ is the number of unknowns)

I'm not able to find it on the net.

What is the idea behind the Cramer's rule? How can I write the Cramer's rule for $n$ equations with $n$ unknowns without memorising any sequence?

EDIT : I did check the Wikipedia and I couldn't understand anything :(

Comment: Did you try [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#General_case)?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I was just about to post the very same comment, word for word, with the same link.

Comment: The Cramer rule only contains determinants. It works for every matrix size, if the matrix is an invertible square matrix guaranteeing a unique solution.

Comment: The matrices emerge by substituting the columns (one by one) by the solution vector $b$ in the equation $Ax=b$. Not difficult to memorize. Divide the  determinants of these matrices by the determinant of $A$, that's all.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I did, I was hoping someone would explain it in easier language. I honestly couldn't understand anything from that :(

Comment: If you don't know what vectors, matrices and determinants are, you need to learn that.  These are explained in any linear algebra text, or on the net.

Comment: To be honest, Cramer's rule for $n \ge 4$ probably isn't worth the amount of computation it involves, it's simpler and faster just to use Gaussian elimination.  (With some possible specialized exceptions for theoretical purposes.)

Comment: @RobertIsrael the proof is rather intuitive, I was actually scared over nothing. I feel stupid now cuz I saw those symbols and discontinued reading. That was actually way lot easier than it looked :-) Took me a while but O well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, but if you want some compact expression for Cramer's rule, probably I can help and provide you with one -- the only thing it requires you to memorize is how to calculate determinants.

**SOLUTION**

Consider the following equation
$$
\underbrace{
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,1}  \\
            a_{2,1}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,1}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,2}  \\
            a_{2,2}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,2}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,n}  \\
            a_{2,n}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,n}  \\
        \end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}_{\hat{A}}
\underbrace{
        \begin{pmatrix}
            x_{1} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            x_{2} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            \cdots                       \\
            x_{n} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
}_{\vec{x}}
= 
\underbrace{
        \begin{pmatrix}
            b_{1} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            b_{2} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            \cdots                       \\
            b_{n} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
}_{\vec{b}},
$$
where $\hat{A}$ and $\vec{b}$ are given and we aim to find $\vec{x}$.
Solution may be written as
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
            x_{1} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            x_{2} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            \cdots                       \\
            x_{n} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
        \end{pmatrix} =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \vec{e}_{1} & \vec{e}_{2} & \dots & \vec{e}_{n} \\
        \begin{matrix}
            b_{1} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            b_{2} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            \cdots                       \\
            b_{n} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,1}  \\
            a_{2,1}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,1}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,2}  \\
            a_{2,2}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,2}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,n}  \\
            a_{2,n}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,n}  \\
        \end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,1}  \\
            a_{2,1}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,1}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,2}  \\
            a_{2,2}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,2}  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
            \cdots  \\
        \end{matrix} &
%
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,n}  \\
            a_{2,n}  \\
            \cdots   \\
            a_{n,n}  \\
        \end{matrix}
    \end{pmatrix}
},
$$
where $\vec{e}_1$, $\dots$, $\vec{e}_n$ are unitary vetors along coordinate axes.

**STRUCTURE OF THE SOLUTION**

I'll rewrite the equation once more to show how it's built
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
            x_{1} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            x_{2} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            \cdots                       \\
            x_{n} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
        \end{pmatrix} =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \boxed{\begin{matrix} \vec{e}_{1} & \vec{e}_{2} & \dots & \vec{e}_{n} \end{matrix}} \\
\boxed{
        \begin{matrix}
            b_{1} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            b_{2} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
            \cdots                       \\
            b_{n} \vphantom{x_{1}^{(1)}} \\
        \end{matrix}} &
%
\boxed{
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n}\\
            a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n}\\
            \cdots  & \cdots  & \cdots & \cdots\\
            a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & a_{n,n}\\
        \end{matrix} 
}
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
\boxed{
        \begin{matrix}
            a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & \cdots & a_{1,n}\\
            a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & \cdots & a_{2,n}\\
            \cdots  & \cdots  & \cdots & \cdots\\
            a_{n,1} & a_{n,2} & \cdots & a_{n,n}\\
        \end{matrix} 
}
    \end{pmatrix}
} =
(-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \boxed{\begin{matrix} \vec{e}_{1} \dots & \vec{e}_{n} \end{matrix}} \\
\boxed{\vec{b}\\} & \boxed{\hspace{1cm}\hat{A}\hspace{1cm}\\}
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        \boxed{\hat{A}}
    \end{pmatrix}
}
$$

**EXAMPLE**

Consider following equations
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
    -2 x_1 + 3 x_2 + x_3 &= 2, \\
    - x_1 - x_2 + 4 x_3 &= 1, \\
    x_1 + x_2 + x_3 &= 1,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
or in matrix form
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
            -2 & 3  & 1 \\
            -1 & -1 & 4 \\
             1 & 1  & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{3} \\
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
2 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Solution is written as
$$
\vec{x} = (-1)
\frac{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        0 & \vec{e}_1 & \vec{e}_2 & \vec{e}_3 \\
            2 & -2 & 3  & 1 \\
            1 & -1 & -1 & 4 \\
            1 &  1 & 1  & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
}{
    \det
    \begin{pmatrix}
        -2 & 3  & 1 \\
        -1 & -1 & 4 \\
         1 & 1  & 1
    \end{pmatrix}
} = \frac{1}{25} \vec{e}_1 + \frac{14}{25} \vec{e}_2 + \frac{2}{5}\vec{e}_3
=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{25} \\
\frac{14}{25} \\
\frac{2}{5} \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
thus $x_1=1/25$, $x_2=14/25$, and $x_3=2/5$.

**REFERENCES**

To read more on the theory everything relies on, you may want to check "[Beginner's guide to mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332410209_Beginner's_guide_to_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" that is written by authors of the formula. Besides they have "[Workbook on mapping simplexes affinely](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/332971934_Workbook_on_mapping_simplexes_affinely)" that contains different examples with similar determinants.